# CPU resources were limited

Tags: limit

- My wp-admin, cpanel and webmail are notified as follows:

Resource Limit Is Reached
The website is temporarily unable to service your request as it exceeded resource limit. Please try again later.his

- Hosting provider give the following reasons:

CPU resources were limited for your site
You have reached entry processes (number of simultaneously running php and cgi scripts, as well as cron jobs and shell sessions) limit 4023 times

The Swift account is allotted the following resources:

Number of Processes: 50. Currently 35. 
Entry Processes: 35. Currently 35
Virtual Memory Usage: 8GB. Currently 653MB
Physical Memory Usage: 1GB. Currently 136.8MB. 
CPU: 100 % of 2 x 2.1 ghz virtual CPU's. Currently at 0.

- What should I do for my sites could be back to normal again?

Thanks & Kind regards, Feby

Answer (score 0):

Login to WHM WebHost Manager as 'root'

Link to Access WHM : https://yourserverIP:2087
Username : root
Password : Enter root password of Server  *******

2. Click on "CloudLinux LVE Manager" under "Server Configuration"

WHM Home » Server Configuration » CloudLinux LVE Manager
In the 'statistics' tab you can check whether any sites hit the Entry process Limit.

3. Click on "Settings" tab. Here you can see Current Entry process Limit set for Domains.
4. Click on "Edit" to increase the Entry process EP for the website.
5. Settings for LVE 502 (Username - website.com)

Concurrent connections (EP) - Here you can see the current Entry process Limit set for the domain, you can enter a new Entry process Limit value.

6. Click on Apply after making changes.

WHM Home » Server Configuration » CloudLinux LVE Manager » Settings » Edit » Apply